# Expectation of logarithm function with chi-square distributed variables

Tags: logarithms, expected-value, chi-squared

How to calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(1+x\right)\right]$ where $x$ denotes a central chi-square distributed variable?
The lower bound and upper bound of this expectation are also of my concern.

Comment: Well, you want to evaluate the integral of $\log(1+x)$ time the Chi-squared pdf. At a glance, have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Probability_density_function